# <a> tag with valid href value wouldn't route when clicked

Tags: html

At https://www.schandillia.com (the demo site), I have a section that looks like this:

[image]

The title on each of these boxes are clickable and meant to route you to the linked page. The cursor even turns into a pointer as it's meant to when hovered over an  element. However, when nothing really happens when the links are clicked. The page stays unchanged. The links themselves work though as can be seen when you select **open link in a new tab** option from the context menu. I see nothing unusual about the markup:

```
<a class="MuiTypography-root MuiLink-root MuiLink-underlineHover jss317 MuiTypography-colorInherit" href="/blog/posts/seventh-post">
  <h4 class="MuiTypography-root jss307 MuiTypography-h4">
    Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires
  </h4>
</a>
```

Do you? What am I doing wrong?

**P.S.**: For what it's worth, this is a React project and the codebase is up at https://github.com/amitschandillia/proost/tree/master/web.

Comment: Link showing Bad gateway.

Comment: Sorry, my server was down for a bit. It shouldn't now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think your link is not clickable because there is something wrong with the HTML tags that you have written.

The HTML piece here:

```
<a class="MuiTypography-root MuiLink-root MuiLink-underlineHover jss317 MuiTypography-colorInherit" href="/blog/posts/seventh-post">
<h4 class="MuiTypography-root jss307 MuiTypography-h4">
Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires
</h4>
</a>
```

Change it to this:

```
<h4 class="MuiTypography-root jss307 MuiTypography-h4">
<a href="/blog/posts/seventh-post" class="MuiTypography-root MuiLink-root MuiLink-underlineHover jss317 MuiTypography-colorInherit">
 Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires
 </a>
 </h4>
```

Your tags were not formed properly. This could be one reason why your link is not working.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You mean an `<h4>` tag cannot go inside an `<a>` tag?